# How to make PictureBox not to fill background after creation?

Tags: c#, gdi+, picturebox

My program has a Form with Picturebox, where I draw some visualization. So I made refreshVisuals method and apply it whenever I need it. But every time when Form appears fot the first time I see how my refreshVisuals() draws right picture on picturebox, and then backgroundColor or backgroundImage fills picturebox. After I move or resize window my visualization again draws right picture. Color.Transparent as background color doesn't help.

How to disable background filling? Is there some event raised after initial background filling?

```
public partial class Visuals: Form
{
//something here

public Visuals()
{
    //some initials here
    this.NeedRefreshPlease +=refreshVisuals; // my event, when something changes, works right.
    this.Activated += refreshVisuals;
    this.Move += refreshVisuals;
    this.AutoSizeChanged += refreshVisuals;
    this.Resize += refreshVisuals;
    this.VisibleChanged += refreshVisuals;
    this.Invalidated += refreshVisuals;
    this.SizeChanged += refreshVisuals;
    this.Shown += refreshVisuals;
    //tried here almost every event, didn't work.
}

public void refreshVisuals(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //actual drawing on Picturebox
}
```

}

Comment: That is dreadful code.  Probably caused by using CreateGraphics().  Stop using it, it is always wrong, use the picture box' Paint event instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SuspendLayout for the control.